# Parse.com Multi-Dimensional Query

Tags: database, multidimensional-array, parse-platform

My database set-up in Parse is:

```
**Promo Class**: *promoGroup* - pointer to Promo_Groups Class

**Promo_Groups Class**: *users* - pointer to _User Class
```

Promo codes can be part of a "group" so that if a user redeems a promo code from the group, they can't redeem any other promo codes from that same group. When a user redeems a promo code, their user object is added in a relation in both the Promo and Promo_Group class entry (It's added to the Promo classes entry for analytic reasons).

How can I query the Promo class, and with the help of the `include/includeKey` feature, see if the user is in the Promo_Group entry's user relation column using just one query?

Comment: Relations do not have `include` feature. You may want to keep an array of users in Promo_Groups, then you may use `var query = new Parse.Query("Promo"); query.include("promoGroup.users");`

Comment: Cheers bud, totally helped me figure out my issue.